# Any reactive HTTP Scala client?

Tags: scala, http, reactive-programming

Is there any really reactive Scala Http client except [play's](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS)? 
By word *reactive* I mean ability to consume response data in chunks with all that non-blocking goodies on handling that portions of data.

Comment: What are you missing from WS? Mainly just curious, but it might help in answering the question also. Have you had a look at [Akka HTTP?](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/http/)

Comment: WS is excellent. Really. Except the fact it brings all play framework as dependency. And just wondering if there any competitors/alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

What about [spray](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-can/http-client/#chunked-requests)? Minimal dependencies and non-blocking data processing with Akka. Look at [example](https://medium.com/@jan______/chunked-responses-from-spray-io-server-22baf3e06a77). Also there are some chunked samples in scala-spray-examples on github.

Comment: Not sure but looks like spray joined akka as akka-http, but it still not released. As for spray itself - good point, ideas behind that lib is very promissing.

Answer (score 0):

Play(2.5) is built on top of Netty . I would suggest spray as well but spray is no longer maintained and has been superseded by Akka HTTP. So, II would suggest you use Akka HTTP or Play. I have to say though, Play is currently working on integrating with Akka HTTP and they currently have an experimental version ready.

If you want to use a standalone reactive http scala client, try Akka HTTP :
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/

The upside of using play, even though it brings in a lot of dependencies, they have a really good test framework for the HTTP side. I would suggest you look at the play documentation, as you will realize you won't need much outside of what they already have.